# Xml serialization with deep indent

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Hi I'm not so good at this but I have a huge interest. :)

How can I serialize this xml?

`<A> 
 <B>
   <C>1600</C> 
 </B>
 <B>
   <C>
     <F>34</F>
   </C> 
 </B>
 <D>
  <E>1400</E>
 </D>
</A>`

Comment: Edit: My problem is how to serialize severel different objects under A.

Comment: You don't "serialize" XML. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Serialize? What do you mean?  If it's already XML ...

Comment: C# is the language sorry

Comment: I have the objects, and it should look like the xml I posted when I have serialized it. but I'm not sure how to make the xml.

Comment: Show the code for the Type of the objects.

Comment: I have a class for A which contains alot of B's with C's in it. That works fine. But I want different types under A, for exampel D. Thats what I'm trying to do. How du I do that.

Comment: I have the code to create a xml with A which contains alot of B's with C's in it. I dont have the code for D, don't know how to do it. 

Is it this you want:
B b = new B();
b.Title = "B Tag";
b.Date = DateTime.Parse("11/10/2010");
b.Sign = "Hello";
  
B b2 = new B();
b2.Title = "B2 Tag";
b2.Date = DateTime.Parse("11/10/2010");
b2.Sign = "Hello";

List<B> bs = new List<B>();
bs.Add(b);
bs.Add(b2);

B.SerializeToXML(bs);

Answer (score 0):

You should add class definitions to your question - that would make it much easier to understand what you need.

For now, I could suggest to look at MSDN: say, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx).

Comment: Thx, got it now. Found an example i msdn.